# Changing Application Icon 

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, icons

I have changed the application Icon in the properties page, tried, then changed my mind,
selected another one, rebuild, file shows the latest icon but soon as i create a shortcut
shows the older icon i wanted to change!!!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be Windows caching the icons.

From http://www.tweakxp.com/article37003.aspx regarding Windows XP

> Just refresh the icon cache by
>   deleting the IconCache.db file from
>   your profile directory (usually
>   /Documents and Settings/Username/Local
>   Settings/Application Data). It will be
>   automatically recreated.

Comment: Try search for `windows 7 icon cache`, but I won't guarantee that the solutions works.